# Using gitlab-ci to build multiple targets best practice

Tags: ios, target, gitlab-ci

I am starting to use Gitlab-ci moving away from Jenkins as since the update to xcode 8 Jenkins stoped working correctly it can not sign the ad-hoc or app-store. tried to fix it and gave up.

So here I am with Gitlab-ci a shinny new hope!!

My project is as follows:

1 project file and multiple targets.

each target is a flavour of the app and I need to get my .gitlab-ci.yml file to for starts create the ad-hoc for each targets..

Di I make 1 runner for each target with a .yml file for each runner or it is possible to have 1 runner for this and 1 .yml file to rule them all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can have multiple .yml files even if you wanted but I'm rather sure you don't need it because that one .gitlab-ci.yml file is split into multiple [stages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#stages) (run consecutively) and each stage can have several different [jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#jobs) (run in parallel). Each job can be run by a different runner using [tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#tags). This alone should give you enough flexibility to perform different builds, make different deployments, etc.

Whether you would have one or multiple runners depends on whether you have any need to have runners located on different servers or having different configuration (e.g. one using shell [executor](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/executors/README.md), other one using a Docker executor). If not, you can use only one runner because it can perform several jobs simultaneously.